# mysql select from 2 tables as (table1.value/table2.value)

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables with same column names, and I need to calculate the increase/decrease percentage change of values from Y2017 to Y2018.

```
Y2018 and Y2017 table are similar (I post only some column name to be short):
+--------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                    | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id_azione                | varchar(8)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| data                     | date          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| total_revenue            | decimal(10,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| cost_of_revenue          | decimal(10,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| gross_profit             | decimal(10,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| general_expenses         | decimal(10,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

For decimal values, I would need to extract a "diff" colum with  increase/decrease percentage change of values from Y2017 to Y2018.

The select works if I select only one column:

```
select Y2018.total_revenue, Y2017.total_revenue, ((Y2018.total_revenue/Y2017.total_revenue*100)-100) as diff   
from Y2018, Y2017  
where Y2018.id_azione = Y2017.id_azione;


| total_revenue | total_revenue | diff     |

|       2930.30 |       2749.80 | 6.564114 |

1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Do I have to make a separate select for each "diff" I want to calculate, or there is a way to do it with only one select?

Thank You

Carlo

Comment: You simply cannot divide all columns in a table by all columns in another table in this way you have to specify the column names in arithmetic or use aggregation if you want over the whole table

Comment: Tell us what you are trying to achieve and someone will suggest a solution. AND provide sample data and expected  output as text.

Comment: Please use modern join syntax, available since SQL-92 (28 years ago).

Answer (score 1):

> The select works if I select only one column...

That's correct. You cannot divide `*` by `*`. You'll need to name each one of the columns there. It may be tedious, but it's the correct way of doing it, according to the SQL Standard.

For example:

```
select
  b.*,
  a.*,
  100.0 * b.total_revenue    / a.total_revenue    - 100 as rev_diff,
  100.0 * b.cost_of_revenue  / a.cost_of_revenue  - 100 as cost_diff,
  100.0 * b.gross_profit     / a.gross_profit     - 100 as profit_diff,
  100.0 * b.general_expenses / a.general_expenses - 100 as exp_diff
from Y2018 b
join Y2017 a on b.id_azione = a.id_azione
```

Also, note that I rephrased each formula by placing `100.0` at the beginning. This ensures floating point calculations, that avoid silent integer roundings.

Comment: It works, I had  forgot to delete a "," from the query. Thank You!

Comment: @Impaler, how could I do if I want diff column  with only 2 decimals?

Comment: @carlolab You can enclose each formula with `TRUNCATE(formula, 2)` to truncate to two decimal places, or with `ROUND(formula, 2)` to round to two decimal places.

Comment: I make mitake  to where to put the TRUNCATE. Finally I discovered thas it works like this:    TRUNCATE(100.0 * b.net_income / a.net_income - 100, 2)  as net_income_diff